# Why do I need a delay before getting an element's dimensions?

Tags: javascript, jquery, event-handling, settimeout

When trying to get elements dimenions during rendering of a page in Jquery, I often find myself having to set timeouts like this:

```
window.setTimeout(function(){
    console.log("calculate footer height");
    console.log( $('div:jqmData(role="footer")') )
    console.log(  wrap.find('.ui-footer').css("height") )
    },0);
```

which returns the correct values (in the case `46px`), while doing this without the timeout

```
    console.log("calculate footer height");
    console.log( $('div:jqmData(role="footer")') )
    console.log(  wrap.find('.ui-footer').css("height") )
```

will return the element, but its width will be `0px`

**Question**:
Why is it like this and more importantly, are there better ways than resorting to `setTimeouts` like in the example? Please note: I cannot influence rendering of the element, as this is done by Jquery Mobile, so the above has to run from a different "location"

Thanks!

Comment: Are you using document ready?

Comment: Where are you putting your code? Just in a script or do you use document ready like @ryan proposses?

Comment: Is the element dynamically-generated?

Comment: beyond `document.ready` use are images involved?   `document.ready` is before images loaded

Comment: @ryan: I'm using `requireJS`, which should start on docReady and `Jquery Mobile`, which I'm manually initializing when the plugin that includes my above snippet triggers.... which could be the reason why it doesn't work. Mh...

Comment: @T.J.Crowder - yes and no, I'm only providing a `div data-role="footer"` with a `ul` for the buttons. Jquery Mobile then takes it, adds a lot of classes and elements. See [here](http://jquerymobile.com/test/docs/toolbars/docs-navbar.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok. Haven't found a solution, but I traced the problem down to the following:

- plugin A gets loaded, initialization prevented, so elements don*t get their dimensions.
- plugin B gets loaded and initliazed, along the way initializing plugin A.
- plugin B then tries to get the element dimensions, but as A hasn't fully run through, the elements are still un-enhanced (= no class, no width)

I haven't really found a fix for this, because
a) I need to manually trigger plugin A (= `Jquery Mobile`), otherwise it will not play nice with `requireJS` (initializing on `mobileinit` vs `docReady`) and
b) my own plugin needs it's event bindings set before Jquery Mobile can init, so I need a manual trigger.

If someone know a workaround for this, I will check as answer.

Thanks for posting.

Answer (score 1):

you should respond to the onload event

for example:

```
$( function() {

    console.log("calculate footer height");
    console.log( $('div:jqmData(role="footer")') );
    console.log(  wrap.find('.ui-footer').css("height") );

} );
```

your timeout allows the browser to render, so you retrieve correct values.
using the onload variant waits until the page is loaded and is triggered then.

often there are some other notations like

```
$( document ).ready( function() { .... });
```

of

```
$().ready( function() { .... });
```

I prefer

```
(function($) {
    $( function() { ... } );
} ( jQuery ) );
```

to ensure $ represents jQuery

Comment: ok. The whole snippet is in a plugin I'm writing using jquery widget factory, so it's already more or less embedded in a structure. Please see my first comment above. The problem might be that when I'm querying for the dimension, the plugin setting the dimensions hasn't been initliazed or fully parsed.